# Simplexml xpath array result

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

I have an xpath query on a simplexml element like so:

```
$theSimpleXmlObject->xpath('//path/to/*/node');
```

it returns an array of results which is great but it is an array of simplexml objects and i just want a flat array.

Is this possible?

Ideally i would have a simple array returned with the matching node values instead of having to iterate over the results to prepare the array.

Comment: `array_map('strval', $array_from_xpath)` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try  in this way to get Array

```
$xml = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($string)), 1);
```

When you cast xml to array it will cast only "first level", so we can made it by convert it in JavaScript Object Notation and decode it again to array. Serialization will not help, becouse it keep data-structure.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit?

Comment: When you cast xml to array it will cast only "first level",  so we can  made it by convert it in JavaScript Object Notation and decode it again to array. Serialization will not help, becouse it keep data-structure.